# Create a table on objective-c code without storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I can't create table on objective-c, cause I start learning objective-c.

Google can't help me, I tried.
I hope what u can help me

//Update: Below Nick showed the correct answer. After some time, I was prompted to answer this question and now I can share with you the answer. I want to be useful for such guys as I was

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Here we initialize the table, create delegates and display it on the screen
    arrData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ONE",@"TWO",,@"THREE", nil];
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource & Delegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return arrData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Cells initialization
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: see this for example : https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26271496/7851805

Comment: @Nick I'm sorry, I don't know how I can vote up to your comment, I can vote up answers. If you'll write answer, I'll vote up it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For default tableview cell with array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ONE",@"TWO",,@"THREE", nil];
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource & Delegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return arrData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it solution have been right and help me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

***IF YOU ARE USING XIB***

You have to create tablviewcell file and design your own cell.

Import your cell file too..

#import "selectedcell.h"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
array =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"AAAA",@"BBBB",,@"CCCC", nil];
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds 
style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.tablview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SelectedTableViewCell" 
bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
self.tablview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SelectedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.label.text = [Nsstring stringwithformate:@"%@",[array objectatindex:indexpath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   //After selecting row
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 50;
}
```

Comment: It's solution have been useful for me. Thank you!